# 'Pub get' and can't build flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

C:\Users\Anmol\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.5.3-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in eshop v2.1.0...
Because no versions of tuple match 2.0.0 and no versions of tuple match >2.0.0 <3.0.0, tuple ^2.0.0 is forbidden.
So, because eshop depends on tuple ^2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because eshop depends on tuple ^2.0.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue is in your `pubspec.yaml`.
Do the following:
In your pubspec.yaml remove the version given to tuple and make it look like this:

```
dependencies:
  tuple: ^2.0.0
```